# Rails: How do you show a (number) difference temporarily?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to implement a reputation system in my app (similar to stackoverflow). I want to be able to show any recent additions or subtractions to the reputation score next to it. What is the best way to go about such implementation?

For e.g Reputation Score: 150 +10  or Reputation Score: 150 -20

The only method I can think of right now is create another column/field called temporary_reputation and keep the most recent addition/subtraction in there. And then maybe create a cron to clear that column every 20-30minutes. Maybe I can do something with the cache?

Comment: Your question seems more to be 2 questions: "How to show ..." and "How to model / store ...", which are 2 different questions in my opinion. Which interests you more? Then edit your own question to ask (only) that one ... (I find both interesting, but for the sake of clarity, ask only one).

Comment: You could use versioning to store every change that's done to your reputation model, and easily navigate its history.

Comment: @mliebelt Isn't how to show the data related to how it is stored? I guess I have a need and trying to figure out how to solve the problem. I'm not set on how storing/showing the data should determine the answer.

Comment: @Robin versioning seems like an interesting way to go about this, would it be considered overkill? I guess I should also move the reputation column from my user table to its own table?

Comment: Yes, it is overkill if displaying the difference is all you wanna do. If you want more features like SO with a complete history, then it might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you suggest will not solve your problem.

I would prefer implementing an extra model eg: `ScoreChange` which will have

- timestamp
- value

and the relations that are needed.

That way for each item with a reputation score you can have an aggregated `score` field and then show all the changes you want.

eg:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :score_changes

def last_changes(n)
  score_changes.last_changes_sum(n)
end

def score_with_last_change(n = 3)
  [score, last_changes(n)]
end
```

and

```
class ScoreChange < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item

  def self.last_changes_sum(n)
    order('timestamp desc').limit(n).pluck(:value).inject(&:+)
  end
end
```